# Can this C code cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

```
int *i;
*i=123;
```

Comment: Always yes no allocated memory for i

Comment: @SjB: not always , the value of the pointer i is completely random, there is a chance its value will actually point to a valid memory location

Comment: Not to mention the fact the code might be running on a machine with no concept of memory segmentation, and thus no possibility of producing a segmentation fault.

Comment: @SjB as suggested by Neil, it currently may or may not cause a segmentation fault, and your answer may be incorrect as in the future it may not be possible if C semantics are changed to prevent this from causing a segmentation fault or from compiling.

Comment: it will produce a seg fault in the best case scenario. If it doesn't it will cause problems that are much harder to debug.

Comment: If you have one of the systems described at http://dspace.dial.pipex.com/town/green/gfd34/art/, the result is much more "interesting" then segmentation faults!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It can, but there again it could do anything - it exhibits what the C Standard calls "[undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)".

Comment: It could even erase your hard drive.  Not bloody likely, but it could.

Comment: Not as unlikely as it might seem. I always used to take the floppies out of my old Z80 CP/M box before I ran some newly assembled code to prevent exactly this happening!

Comment: It could erase your hard drive as far as the C language is concerned. These days a process doing undefined behavior is still subject to the operating system's security rules, so chances are slim. Still, if you've used `sudo` recently...

Comment: Unless you have a user account just to sandbox your C compiler, your user privileges are probably enough to delete anything you care about on your hard drive, even if it can't be fully erased.

Comment: Remember, the compiler is allowed to generate anything at all for undefined behavior, so starting a game of pong is allowed!

Answer (score 30):

Yes. There is no allocated memory to place the value `123`.

Like initializing a variable like `int` is not guaranteed to be `0`, an `int*` isn't guaranteed to be a safe address.

It also could potentially lead to data corruption.

Comment: it is not guaranteed to cause a segfault though. It could by happenstance point to a writable location.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

Answer (score 2):

Rough odds on a 32-bit operating system:

- Odds to trigger a hardware exception: 99.9995%
- Odds to corrupt program state: 0.0005%
- Odds to accidentally hit the right memory location: 1 in 2 billion

Estimates only to demonstrate orders of magnitude.  Relevant only for a Release build.  If it does corrupt program state then the odds it will do so consistently climb to close to 100%.  A good compiler makes the hardware exception odds 100% in the Debug build.  Get a good compiler.

Comment: Yes, i will be initialized to a random value. But who said anything about a linear distribution?

Comment: I think you mean a "uniform" distribution.  But if that code was executed just after calling a function that left a pointer in that stack location, then odds are actually very good that it points to valid memory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the code you posted can cause a segmentation fault.  You've got a pointer which is uninitialized (doesn't point to any known location) and you then use it to store something.  Where does the 'something' go?  Good question, to which there is no consistent answer.

You need to initialize that pointer.  For example:

```
int target = 0;
int *i = &target; 

printf("target=%d\n", target);
*i=123; 
printf("target=%d\n", target);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`int *i;` This allocates a memory for pointer but this variable is not initialized so it's value is totally random. Then you dereference it so you have a random address and perform a write to this place in the memory but 1) you don't know where the place is 2) this place probably is not yours. You can fix it with initialization like `int * i = ( int* ) malloc( sizeof(int) )`

Comment: C does not have the `new` operator.

Comment: You are right, my fault. There is function malloc. I'll fix it.

Comment: The cast from `void*` to `int*` is unnecessary in C and bad practice. `int *i = malloc(sizeof(int));` is perfectly sufficient.